# I cannot execute file compiled by haskell compilier

Tags: linux, haskell, linux-mint

I want to execute a binary file, which was compiled by the GHC Haskell compiler.

If I execute `./main.hi` I get:

```
bash: ./main.hi: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

and if I write `./main` I get

```
bash: ./main: No such file or directory but file exists.
```

Result of the `ls` command:

```
log.txt  main.hi  main.hs  main.o
```

`chmod` didn't help to fix the problem. My Haskell code:

```
module HelloWorld where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Files named *.hi are not supposed to be executable. Which commands did you type ? Does this work ? `ghc main.hs  -o ./main.x`  and then:  `./main.x`

Comment: Generally I would recommend not invoking GHC manually at all. Let `cabal` do it for you. Cf https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/getting-started.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` must appear in a module named `Main` -- or, with GHC, you may (must) inform it of your alternative main module's name. So, you can either change your file to

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

or change your compilation line to include the `-main-is` argument; for example:

```
% ghc -main-is HelloWorld main.hs
```

After making either of these changes, you should see an additional file in the list:

```
% ls
log.txt  main  main.hi  main.hs  main.o
```

This new file is the executable, and it can be run with `./main`.

Comment: Please vote for answer if it is normal answer.

Comment: @Ioann If you are asking how people normally deal with this, the answer there is that they use `cabal` or `stack`, and do not invoke GHC themselves. But both of those tools also have the `main-is` concept inside. e.g. a cabal stanza for an executable might begin `executable hello-world\n    main-is: main.hs`.